# Trying to get data from localstorage on "store" event to pass to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state, react-props

I'm trying to make a page that will live update when the form on the sidebar changes. I was doing it by making an update to the database on each keystroke but figured that wasn't good so I wanted to use local storage. I'm able to update the local storage key with each key stroke, but I haven't been able to get the data from local storage. I'm trying to use the on storage event, but it doesn't seem to trigger. Messed with useEffect too but no luck. Any tips? Also, just to note, the userData that is being passed into the function is from the actual database query, then I'm trying to replace it in the previewData state. The page structure is: Edit component has EditForm and PreviewPage as children. Thanks for taking a look.

```
function Preview({ userData }) {
  console.log(userData);
  const [previewData, setPreviewData] = useState(userData);
  console.log(previewData);


    window.onstorage = () => {
      console.log('on storage');
      const localStorageData = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem('pagePreviewData')
      );
      setPreviewData(localStorageData);
    };

  const theme = previewData.theme;
  
  return (
    <div
      className={theme}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'var(--background-default)',
        padding: '0 25px',
      }}
    >
      <Header userData={previewData}></Header>

      <main>
        <PageBody userData={previewData}></PageBody>
      </main>
      <FooterPage userData={previewData}></FooterPage>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Preview;
```

And this is the function I'm calling onKeyUP to set to localStorage

```
const handlePreview = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('pagePreviewData', JSON.stringify(updateFormState))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that the React state is the canonical state and `localStorage` updates from the React state rather than the other way around.

Even so, updating `localStorage` on every keystroke might be unnecessary and excessive.

`setPreviewData` is now the method to update the data.  You can pass this down as a prop or potentially use [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make it available to deeply nested children.

```
const [previewData, setPreviewData] = useState(userData);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("pagePreviewData", JSON.stringify(previewData));
}, [previewData]);
```